Parameter types not inferred from optional function types
I use a library react-international-phone for phone input integration and it exposes UsePhoneInputConfig type, which looks like this:
type UsePhoneInputConfig = {
  onChange?: (data: { phone: string }) => void;
};

In my wrapper component over this library I have handleOnChange, which calls onChange prop, and is assigned to the function type from the library:
  const handleOnChange: UsePhoneInputConfig['onChange'] = useCallback((data) => {
    onChange(data.phone);
  }, [onChange]);

I was expecting the data type to be the object { phone: string }, but it says Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006). When I make the onChange a required type from UsePhoneInputConfig, it infers the type properly.
Here is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@test/*": ["./test/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

TypeScript Playground

Your demo is not equivalent; the difference is that you're assigning the result of calling useCallback with the function to the typed variable, not the function itself: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhACgCwPYDsIEl1gK7ADCGAZgJYDmUAvFAN4BQUUGhyAhuhRAPwBcUABQATdsHYC6UMGkwC4wAE5kuUAL4BKGgD4oAN1RlhAbgZrTDEnnQBjYGQxQ0JADwAxKBAAewCOmFwUG7Wdg7o2oIkAm4a0fRMUIoQwHiK6FAkpmoMDDYYChkhAvBIsti4BMTo5BQA2gDkrBxcEPUAujROqCSCImLsWtS6jMx56AVenaLiAHQyGBAWo-moADYQM6uoFIJeGmYapkA

Here's a shorter example, with actual React types: https://tsplay.dev/NrYY0w

I wan't able to load React from the playground, that's why I left useCallback. And you're absolutely right and thanks for the simplified version of the question.

Given that your function will exist even if the one it's wrapping doesn't, something like https://tsplay.dev/N9779W would work, but that doesn't explain why the optional breaks the inference.

Simultaneous contextual type inference and generic type argument inference is always a sore spot in TypeScript.  I believe you are hitting ms/TS#50719 and while it's considered a bug, it doesn't look like anyone knows how to fix it properly. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

sure, go ahead thanks.

This is considered a bug in TypeScript, as described in microsoft/TypeScript#50719. Apparently the initial inference candidate for the generic type argument for useCallback() includes undefined, which fails to meet the Function constraint, and then it falls back to the constraint, and then there's nothing from which to contextually infer the callback parameter type.
So far nobody's been able to fix the bug without causing other problems. It's listed as "Help Wanted" so if you or anyone you know wants to look at fixing it, they might accept a pull request for it.  Until and unless it gets fixed, you'll need to work around it or give up.

One workaround described in the issue itself is to rewrite the useCallback() signature to remove the constraint, and add it back as an intersection:
// merge
declare module 'react' {
    function useCallback<T>(callback: T & Function, deps: React.DependencyList): T;
}

This uses module augmentation to merge another call signature for useCallback into the definition, without needing to mess with React's typings directly. Now when you call your functions it works without a problem:
const handleOnChange: UsePhoneInputConfig["onChange"] = useCallback((data) => { }, []);

But this might be overkill for you, and instead you should just help the compiler out by either annotating the parameter type, or manually specifying the generic type argument... or, you could use the satisfies operator to provide a more useful contextual type:
const handleOnChange: UsePhoneInputConfig["onChange"] = useCallback(
  (data) => { }, []
) satisfies NonNullable<UsePhoneInputConfig["onChange"]>; // okay

Playground link to code
